# want to get Sprite Touch but not on transparent Area

Tags: android, andengine, game-physics

I am developing a wallpaper in Andengine, in this wallpaper i want the sprite to interact on touch but i dont want the sprite to interact when user touches on the transparent area of Sprite (should interact when user touches coloured area of sprite), how is it possible..Please help...i will be very thankful..

Comment: I believe this will be a challenge since there is no standard way to do this. Feel free to implement this feature and contribute it to the AndEngine community.

Comment: its really strange and shocking that there is no such method or solution has been introduced till now to overcome this problem..

Comment: Not really shocking, it might involve working with OpenGL on a lower than usual level. You can easily get the local touch coordinates on the Sprite, maybe you can find out whether the sprite contains transparent area on the place you touched and let such TouchEvents fall through.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use some other method for hit detection. 
There is this guy's implementation of pixel-level collision detection:
https://github.com/m5/andengine-pixel-perfect

And there is the Box2D version. Try using Physics Editor (http://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor) to make your box2D shapes match your sprite outlines.

Comment: Yup..i were thinking that physics can handle this isssue..but i just wanted to make it happen with simple sprites..but thank you Plastic Sturgoen and JohnEye for helping and giving me ur wise opinions :)  thank alot

Comment: @UsmanIftakhar: I am also facing the same problem. Did you get the solution for that?

Comment: @Plastic Sturgeon: I use Pixel Perfect collision. But there is no solution there.